# React select custom input won't hide placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am following the React Select docs to alter the Input component of the Select (to add more properties I need to the default input:

```
const Input = ({ innerProps }) => {
  return <input {...innerProps} {...somethingElseINeed} />;
};

const CustomSelect = props => {
  return (
    <Select components={{ Input }}></Select>
  );
};
```

It does add a custom input, however it:

1. Lacks any of the styles and aria attributes the original input has.
2. Doesn't hide a placeholder when focused.

I tried to use `getStyled` and `theme` properties that shoold come by default, but no luck.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Producible example?...

Comment: OK, I managed to solve 2 by passing `onChange={props.onChange}` but I still can't get the styles to work. `getStyles('input', props)` adds something but it doesn't look like the original input.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

What about aria props, you can get it from input props, that has appropriate view

[image]

**2)**

if you look at react-select components tree you will see that RS paste placeholder into another component

[image]

and you can remove placeholder on focus like that just add styles with using state:

```
const styles = {
   placeholder(base, state) {
    return {
      ...base,
      display: state.isFocused && 'none',
    };
  }
}
```